# Passing a parameter to a bash alias

Tags: bash

I can't seem to make a bash alias that takes in a parameter. Here is what I put into the .bashrc file:

**alias test='history | grep "$1"**

This is what I input into the terminal:

**test history**

This is what I get:

**grep: history: No such file or directory**

How can I fix this?

Comment: `alias` does not take positional parameters. If you want to use positional parameters, you must declare a function and then alias the function.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

The bash `alias` does not allow the use of arguments (positional parameters) directly. You can take arguments by declaring a function and then aliasing that function.

In your case you can do (in your `.bashrc`):

```
showhist() {
    [ -z "$1" ] && { printf "usage:  hist <search term>\n"; return 1; }
    history | grep "$1"
    return 0
}
```

followed by:

```
alias hist='showhist'
```

Then just use `hist searchterm` on the command line.